# Razor Syntax Value not getting set in TextBoxFor

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

This is what I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Windscreen_Laminated, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" , Value = "1" })
```

When I run the page, value is shown as a word and not value=1

I have tried

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Windscreen_Laminated, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" , @Value = "1" })
```

as well but it doesn't work. I know I'm missing something small but I can't see it.

Comment: What is value showing in the text field?  `value is shown as a word`-What does it mean?

Comment: In the text field nothing is shown. But when I inspect, I can see that value is shown as a word without the ="1"

Comment: `<input asp-for="Windscreen_Laminated" value="1" class="form-control" />` try this as your project is in ASP.NET Core

Comment: What is the data type of Windscreen_Laminated ?

Comment: So meaning stop using razor and use pure html?

Comment: Windscreen_Laminated is an input text box that takes numbers

Comment: Its okay. I think I found an answer. I set the value from the controller side instead.

Comment: the simple meaning of TextBoxFor is it will get value from model property....and the value of property will be the value of textbox....do it from controller side